# Is there an app that will show me total word count across all applications over a period of time?

Tags: software-recommendation

Does anyone know of an application or service that I can enable that will log and record a count of the total number of words that I've typed over the course of a day?

I don't want or need a full keyboard log of all words, and I certainly don't want any of that being stored. I just want to know how many words and characters I've typed over the course of the day, irrespective of application.

Comment: For backstory: I'm the lead engineer of a company that has workers primary working remotely, and we handled a few crazy crises today and I feel like I've typed 20,000 words today (including all of these). I'd like to count and log all of these words and keypresses and hopefully chart them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mac Word Counter](http://wordcounterapp.com/) should help you.

From the above-linked splash page:

> The Word Counter …
>
> gives immediate feedback on your productivity as a writer.
>
> encourages you by showing you your daily output.
>
> gives you clarity about your daily goals.
>
> keeps a complete history of your daily achievements.
>
> assists with finding your perfect writing environment.
>
> counts what counts: words – the ultimate metric for writing.

Comment: Thank you so much. This app is perfect. I bought it. Excellent suggestion.